In Django, how do I pass custom information from the user signup html form to the models?
In my Django project, I have two types of profiles (person and business). Based on the form a user fills in signup.html (which is very rudimentary right now) one of the types profiles will be created.
(My implementation is based on this - section Extending User Model Using a One-To-One Link).
models.py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    company_name = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    phone_number = models.TextField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    is_vendor = models.BooleanField(default=False)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()

views.py:
class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2',)

    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'placeholder': 'Your username',
        'class': 'w-full py-4 px-6 rounded-xl'
    }))
    ...


class BusinessSignupForm(SignupForm):
    class Meta(SignupForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = SignupForm.Meta.fields + ('company_name',)

    company_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'placeholder': 'Company name',
        'class': 'w-full py-4 px-6 rounded-xl'
    }))


class PersonSignupForm(SignupForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = SignupForm.Meta.fields + ('phone_number',)

    phone_number = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'placeholder': 'Phone number',
        'class': 'w-full py-4 px-6 rounded-xl'
    }))

views.py:
def signup(request):
    form_personal = PersonSignupForm()
    form_business = BusinessSignupForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'personal_account' in request.POST:
            form = PersonSignupForm(request.POST)
        elif 'business_account' in request.POST:
            form = BusinessSignupForm(request.POST)
        else:
            return render(request, 'core/signup.html', {'error': 'Invalid form submission'})

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/login/')  # Redirect to your home page after successful signup
        else:
            print("FORM IS NOT VALID")
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form_personal = PersonSignupForm()
        form_business = BusinessSignupForm()

    return render(request, 'core/signup.html', {'form_personal': form_personal,
                                                'form_business': form_business})


signup.html:
{% block content %}
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane container active" id="personal_account">
            <h3>Personal Account</h3>
            <form method="post" action=".">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form_personal.non_field_errors }}
                {{ form_personal.as_p }}
                <input type="hidden" name="personal_account" value="true">
                <button class="py-4 px-8 text-lg bg-teal-500 hover:bg-teal-7 rounded-xl text-white">Create personal account</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane container fade" id="business_account">
            <h3>Business Account</h3>
            <form method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form_business.non_field_errors }}
                {{ form_business.as_p }}
                <input type="hidden" name="business_account" value="true">
            <button class="py-4 px-8 text-lg bg-teal-500 hover:bg-teal-7 rounded-xl text-white">Create business account</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

My questions:

During sign up, I can see all the expected parameters that a user has to fill (i.e., phone number for personal account and company name for business account). I don't see those fields in the database (even after migrations). I can only see username, email and password. Why is that so, and how can I ensure that the parameters I added (phone#, company name) are saved in the database?

I want to set the type of the account based on the form a user fills. So, if the user fills personal form, is_vendor will be false, and true if business form is filled. How do I convey this information to create_user_profile and save_user_profile?



Add list_display to your admin.py and that will show the other fields in your model.

list_display = [user, location, company_name, phone_number, is_vendor,]


Maybe you can have a drop-down where the user will choose what form to fill. if he chooses personal, set is_vendor to false else set to true


It seems to me the example you're using assumes one profile table. When you update or create a user, populating the profile values with the profile link, the create and save functions save the profile when user.save() is called. Are you using two profile tables (business and personal)? I don't think that would work. Otherwise I don't think you need anything, just populate the user.profile.* fields for business or personal before user.save().

@JohnBayko yes, one profile table, two types of profiles (differentiated by the is_vendor vairiable).

Thank you @16171413, the suggestion worked.

Thank you @JohnBayko, the suggestion worked.

@16171413 and my comments should be written as answers, so the question can be marked as answered. I'll get around to mine.
